# How to project an image/video on a moving object?

Tags: rendering, light

I would like to project an image or a video like a real life projector on moving objects.
Is there a picture/video projector like a light source?

With the old version of blender we could use a spot image instead of a colour.
It is not the case anymore in the newer version.

Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Actually, this is still possible using cycles in the spotlight with material nodes. There is some math you need to do with the vector so that the image comes out straight, but it can be done.

Comment: Thanks I was with eevee.. I will try cycles